# $N=2^8\times3^7\times5^6$, if $A\times B=N$, how many different HCFs can $A$ and $B$ have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My approach:-

The HCFs will have some powers of $2,3,5$:- and for different HCFs $2$ can have powers of $0,1,2,3,4$; $3$ can have powers of $0,1,2,3$; and $5$ can have powers of $0,1,2,3$; so count of different HCFs= $5\times4\times4=80$;

My answer did match with the answer in the book, however I have a doubt in the explanation they have used to arrive at the answer and that is they found out the number of factors of N which are perfect square so $2$ can have the powers of $0,2,4,6,8$  ; $3$ can have the powers $0,2,4,6$; and $5$ will have powers of $0,2,4,6$; so total perfect square factors - $5\times4\times4=80 $ ways

is there any relation between HCFs and perfect squares functionality , why are the answers matching ? I did try for small numbers and the answer through both approaches are still matching, why is it happening like this ?

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Or `\cdot` for $\cdot$

Comment: Thank you ! edited the post

Comment: Hint: $2^n$ can be the HCF iff $(2^n)^2|N$.

Comment: thank u ! so if $2^2$ has to be HCF, I would require $2^2$ for 1 variable and at least $2^2$ as well for the other variable , is it what u want to convey ? can u provide more hints, I am not understanding how is square thing coming up

Answer (score 1):

If you find how many perfect squares divide $N$ the square root of each is a possible HCF.  You take that square root and assign the factors to both A and B then assign the remaining factors so they do not raise the HCF.  One way is to assign all the remaining ones to A.

It is really the same computation you are doing.  They count the even numbers less than or equal to the power of each prime.  You count all the numbers less than or equal to half the power of each prime.  Either approach gives the $5,4,4$ that you multiplied together.

Comment: Thank you !, I cant understand why square roots of perfect squares will give us required HCFs , can you explain that part ; I verified this with small numbers, but can't understand how square root of perfect squares are related to the HCFs

Comment: A perfect square has an even number of factors of each prime.  You can take its square root and get an integer.  You decided that the HCF could have from $0$ to $ 4$ powers of $2$.  They decided that a perfect square could have an even number from $0$ to $8$ powers of $2$.  When they take the square root that leaves $0$ to $4$ powers of $2$ just like you found.  You are finding the square root for a possibility of the HCF, making it a part of $A$, then copying it to be a part of $B$.

Comment: If suppose I have a HCF with 2^1 as a term in it along with some powers of 3 and 5, so what I am doing is taking the square root of 2^1 which gives 2^0.5 and assigning to A and B ?   I can see that their powers are twice than what I have taken for my case, but I cant understand the rationale of them doing this, why did they take perfect square factors only and not perfect cubes or some other powers? could you please edit your answer to help me with this query, it would be really grateful !

Comment: If the HCF has $2^1$ the square has $2^2$.  You take the square root of that to get $2^1$ and say both $A$ and $B$ have a factor $2^1$ and one of them has no more factors of $2$.  In your approach you say the HCF has factor $2^1$ so both $A$ and $B$ have a factor $2^1$ and one of them has no more factors of $2$.  You take perfect square factors so you can give the square root to both $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 0):

Something interesting that I found, is your problem **may** follow the [HyperGeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) or [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) distribution.

Ie. Let $A = 2^{m}3^75^6$, $B= 2^{8 - m}$ where $m$ is variable and $0 \le m \le 8$.

We can have the cases:

$$\big[m = 8\big] \to HCF = 1, \big[m = 7\big] \to HCF = 2, \big[m = 6\big] \to HCF = 4$$

$$\big[m = 5\big] \to HCF = 8, \big[m = 4\big] \to HCF = 16$$

After this we obtain repetition. This could be considered one distribution for the prime factor of $2$.

You can create $2$ other independent distributions for prime factors $3$ and $5$. Maybe then, you can add them to create a combined one and calculate you required total.